# Rotating Rectangles Around Circle Perimeter on Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to create a little circular "equalizer" effect using JavaScript and HTML canvas for a little project I'm working on, and it works great, except one little thing. It's just a series of rectangular bars moving in time to an mp3 - nothing overly fancy, but at the moment all the bars point in one direction (i.e. 0 radians, or 90 degrees).

I want each respective rectangle around the edge of the circle to point directly away from the center point, rather than to the right. I have 360 bars, so naturally, each one should be 1 degree more rotated than the previous.

I thought that doing angle = i*Math.PI/180 would fix that, but it doesn't seem to matter what I do with the rotate function - they always end up pointing in weird and wonderful directions, and being translated a million miles from where they were. And I can't see why. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

My frame code, for reference, is as follows:

```js
function frames() {

  // Clear the canvas and get the mp3 array
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(frames);
  musicArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(musicArray);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  bars = 360;


  for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {

    // Find the rectangle's position on circle edge
    distance = 100;
    var angle = i * ((Math.PI * 2) / bars);
    var x = Math.cos(angle) * distance + (canvas.width / 2);
    var y = Math.sin(angle) * distance + (canvas.height / 2);
    barWidth = 5;
    barHeight = (musicArray[i] / 4);

    // Fill with a blue-green gradient
    var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(x, 0, x + 40, 0);
    grd.addColorStop(0, "#00CCFF");
    grd.addColorStop(1, "#00FF7F");
    ctx.fillStyle = grd;

    // Rotate the rectangle according to position
    // ctx.rotate(i*Math.PI/180); - DOESN'T WORK

    // Draw the rectangle
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, barHeight, barWidth);

  }
```

Comment: All you should have to do is rotate, then draw. The coordinates for the rectangle shouldn't include any angle calculation.

Comment: When you can't see the wood for the trees because you've been fixated on doing things the wrong way round. Oops, my bad! Don't I feel quite the fool now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity I've removed part of your code. I'm using rotate as you intended. Also I'm using `barHeight = (Math.random()* 50);` instead your `(musicArray[i]/4);` because I wanted to have something to show.

Also I've changed your bars to 180. It's very probable that you won't have 360 bars but 32 or 64 or 128 or 256 . . . Now you can change the numbers of bare to one of these numbers to see the result.

I'm drawing everything around the origin of the canvas and translating the context in the center.

I hope it helps.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("c");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = canvas.width = 400;
let ch = canvas.height = 400;


let bars = 180;
let r = 100;

ctx.translate(cw / 2, ch / 2)

for (var i = 0; i < 360; i += (360 / bars)) {

  // Find the rectangle's position on circle edge

  var angle = i * ((Math.PI * 2) / bars);
  //var x = Math.cos(angle)*r+(canvas.width/2);
  //var y = Math.sin(angle)*r+(canvas.height/2);
  barWidth = 2 * Math.PI * r / bars;
  barHeight = (Math.random() * 50);


  ctx.fillStyle = "green";

  // Rotate the rectangle according to position
  // ctx.rotate(i*Math.PI/180); - DOESN'T WORK

  // Draw the rectangle
  ctx.save();
  ctx.rotate(i * Math.PI / 180);

  ctx.fillRect(r, -barWidth / 2, barHeight, barWidth);

  //ctx.fillRect(r ,0, barHeight, barWidth);

  ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: From a mathematical standpoint, it looks like I've been doing my angle calculations at the wrong point. Thanks for the feedback, it's working fine now!

Comment: One slight issue: you need to center the rectangle or the bar won't actually be perpendicular to the edge of the circle. It's not as obvious with small bars, but if you reduce the number of bars you can see what's going on. The line should be `ctx.fillRect(r, -barWidth/2, barHeight, barWidth);`

Comment: And instead of  `ctx.save();
  ctx.rotate(i * Math.PI / 180); ... ctx.restore()` you can do `
  ctx.rotate((Math.PI * 2) / bars);` the rotation will add up and you avoid 360 calls to the expensive save + restore methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, I'm preserving your initial trigonometry approach.
But instead of rectangles I used lines, I don't think it makes a difference for you, if what you need is **bars moving in time to an mp3** all you need to do is change the `var v = Math.random() + 1;` to a reading from the Amplitude, and those bars will be dancing.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("c");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 170;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2)
ctx.lineWidth = 2;

let r = 40;
let bars = 180;

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(-100, -100, 200, 200)

  for (var i = 0; i < 360; i += (360 / bars)) {
    var angle = i * ((Math.PI * 2) / bars);
    var x = Math.cos(angle) * r;
    var y = Math.sin(angle) * r;

    ctx.beginPath();
    var v = Math.random() + 1;
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x * v, y * v)

    grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(x, y, x*2, y*2);
    grd.addColorStop(0, "blue");
    grd.addColorStop(1, "red");
    ctx.strokeStyle = grd;
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

setInterval(draw, 100)
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Your angle calculation should be `var angle = i * ((Math.PI * 2) / 180);` (not based on the number of bars) Otherwise, it doesn't draw correctly when the number of bars is changed.